# Apach POI Word: find text and change font

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to find all occurencies of some text in `XWPFDocument` and set its font. Cannot understand how to get selection (`Run` object maybe?) based on `Scanner` or something like this.

```
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\temp\\document1.docx"))){
        XWPFParagraph par = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = par.createRun();
        run.setText("Абзац создан командой doc.createParagraph()");
        par = doc.createParagraph();
        run = par.createRun();
        run.setText("Чтобы хорошо читалось, на doc.createParagraph() наложен стиль");
        XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(we.getText());
        Pattern words = Pattern.compile("doc.createParagraph()");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String key = scanner.findInLine(words);
            run.getTextPosition();
            while (key != null) {
                scanner.next();                
                key = scanner.findInLine(words);
           }
           scanner.nextLine();
        }
        doc.write(fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edited after @AlexisDelahaye answer.** Current workaround is remove existing Runs and create new:

```
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\temp\\document1.docx"))){
        // Простой абзац с текстом
        String specText = "doc.createParagraph\\(\\)";
        XWPFParagraph par = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = par.createRun();
        run.setText("Абзац создан командой doc.createParagraph()");
        par = doc.createParagraph();
        run = par.createRun();
        run.setText("Чтобы хорошо читалось, на doc.createParagraph() наложен стиль");
        // Смена шрифта для вхождения текста в каждый абзац
        for (XWPFParagraph curPar : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            String parText = curPar.getText();
            boolean endWithSpec = parText.endsWith(specText.replace("\\", ""));
            curPar.removeRun(0);
            for (String curPart : parText.split(specText)) {
                XWPFRun r = curPar.createRun();
                r.setText(curPart);
                r.setFontSize(10);
                r = curPar.createRun();
                r.setText(specText.replace("\\", ""));
                r.setFontSize(20);
            }
            if (!endWithSpec) {
                curPar.removeRun(curPar.getRuns().size() - 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, do you have some code where you parse your XWPDFDocument ?

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye added my draft code

Answer (score 2):

Found this [POI-XWPF quick guide](https://poi.apache.org/document/quick-guide-xwpf.html).
 You're right you need to use Run object

> Specific Text Extraction
>
> To get specific bits of text, first create a
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.XWPFDocument.
>
> Select the **IBodyElement** of interest (Table, Paragraph etc), and from
>   there get a **XWPFRun**.
>
> Finally **fetch** the text and **properties** from that.

So your code may look like this

```
List<XWPFRun> runs = par.getRuns();
   for(int i = 0 ; i < runs.size() - 1 ; i++) {
      XWPFRun run = runs.get(i);
      int index=0;
      // a run contains many text so you want to parse them as well :
      String text = run.getText(index);
      while(text !=null ){
         if(text.contains("occurencyYourLookingFor")) {
           run.setFontFamily("Arial");
         }
         text = run.getText(++index);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly its not working. First text is String and doesnt have setFontFamily method. Second, if I replace text.setFont... with run.setFont style will be applied to all Run, not to my text wich is only small part of Run.

Comment: yes you're right , I replaced text with run  ! 

I saw you managed to find a workaround, great :)